# Errors while enabling ProGuard - Android Development

Tags: java, android, gradle, proguard

I'm getting following errors while 'Generate Signed APK' when I enable minify on build.gradle. Can anyone show me where is the issue? I'm unable to find since I'm new to android development and it doesn't show any class names related to my files

```
org.gradle.initialization.ReportedException: org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Caused by: org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
Caused by: org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
... 3 more

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Job failed, see logs for details
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.ProGuardTransform.transform(ProGuardTransform.java:196)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:221)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:217)
at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102)
```

Comment: Try to add `--info --stacktrace --debug` arguments to the gradle command to get more datails

Comment: Go to gradle event log and see there which thing is making this issue.

Comment: also try clean and rebuild